# What is the checkbox default size

Tags: android, checkbox, size

`checkbox` has fixed size. I wonder `checkbox` default dip size. Or how can I get default dip size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `onWindowFocusChanged` method and inside it you can calculate the `CheckBox` width/height programmatically

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

     int checkBoxWidthInPx = mCheckBox.getWidth(); // return the width of your checkbox, in pixels.
     int checkBoxHeightInPx = mCheckBox.getHeight();

     // conver px to dp
     int checkBoxWidthInDp = checkBoxWidthInPx / this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density
     int checkBoxHeightInDp = checkBoxHeightInPx / this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density 
}
```